# change Rstudio R version from outside Rstudio

Tags: rstudio

I changed Rstudio's R version to a non-default one from Tools-options. Now when I reopen Rstudio, it fails to start. Just a blank window with Rstudio title. Uninstall and reinstall didn't help.

Is there a way to change Rstudio's R version from outside Rstudio, say a config file?

Answer (score 3):

OK, found the config in the file

AppData\Roaming\RStudio\desktop.ini